# How can I set up an alternative X11 window manager in Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, mac, window-manager

I've tried to install an X11 window manager in Mac OS X 10.6.5 such as ratpoison via fink, but I can't get it to start.

I am also thinking about getting xmonad to work in 10.6.5, does anyone know how to set up such a window manager?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Xmonad help page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_on_Apple_OSX) on HaskellWiki has brief instructions for getting Xmonad running on Snow Leopard. You may need to read through the instructions for older versions if some problems arise.